# Which collection data is suitable for calculating soil moisture index using Landsat 8?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-index, vegetation-index

I am trying to compute soil moisture index using Landsat 8 collection 1 level 1, but it seems that I am not computing it properly. My range is not 0 to 1, as it should. Values of my variables can be seen in the last image.

Here is my procedure:

1. Radiance Value using equation:
   [image]
2. Brightness Temperature in Kelvin using equation:

   [image]
3. NDVI Calculation using NDVI=(NIR-RED)/(NIR+RED).
4. For Vegetation Fraction I am writing down lowest (-0.20) and highest (0.66) NDVI values, and then I compute it using formula:

   [image]
5. Emissivity using equation, 0.004 * Pv + 0.98.
6. LST = (Brightness Temperature) / ( 1 + (((Brightness Temperature *
   0.00108)/1.4388) * Ln(Emissivity)) )

   0.00108 -> wavelength of emitted radiance for band 10
7. In order to find “LSTmax = a1 + b1 * NDVI” and “LSTmin = a2 + b2 * NDVI” I create a Fishnet (Taking samples from my study area with x and y coordinates which x is NDVI and y is LST). After that, I export the samples (table) with NDVI and LST values of my study area to excel. There, I have to split NDVI to some groups (I don't consider NDVI values less than 0) and for each group I find max and min LSTs. Then, I match each max and min LST with each NDVI pair and I get a graph like the one bellow (last image). In the end, using linear regression I find that LSTmax=-15.28*NDVI+317.87, LSTmin=4.40*NDVI+297.09

[image]

As you can see in the last image, I tried to find SMI with LST, LSTmax, LSTmin but still my values are -0.48 to 1.16 and not 0 to 1.

I would like to ask, Is the Fishnet tool a wrong approach, that’s why the range is not correct? May you please express your opinion about my wrong range?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you need to expand your question and explain how you are creating the SMI you are currently computing?

Comment: @Hornbydd I am computing it as shown above (I posted every step).

Comment: @Hornbydd On the fraction SMI=(LSTmax-LST)/(LSTmax-LSTmin),I saw that LSTmax-LST gets higher than LSTmax-LSTmin, as a result there are values greater than 1. Also, in some pixels LSTmax-LST is less than 0 so, minus appears in the range. Nevertheless it shouldn't be like that and the range should be 0 to 1. I still can't understand why am I wrong...

Comment: It would be wise to share your data (LST, NDVI etc) so others can reproduce the error. The way it is now it's very difficult to say what's wrong. Also, include screenshots of what you tried to do (e.g., how you calculated the LSTmax) as well.

Comment: @NIkos I uploaded more info !